# Unexpected Token `}`

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using `javascript` and `react` and for some reason I am getting a strange token error.

Here is the code where the error is occurring:

```
renderNavBar() {
        if (!this.userHash) {
            return server_1.default.renderToString(React.createElement(navComponent.navBarNoUser, null));
        }
    }
```

The typescript:

```
renderNavBar() {
        if (!this.userHash) {
            return ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<navComponent.navBarNoUser />);
        }
    }
```

If I comment out the `return ReactDOMServer` line then there is no error. Why is this error occurring?

I also passed the function through `jslint` and I did not get this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: You may check the navComponent.navBarNoUser code check if there are any issue replace the different component to check the issue

Comment: Usualy a function definition as `function` before its name unless you are in `class` definition. Is this the whole code or is there more to this file?

Putting `function` before `renderNavBar` does not return the error, but is potentially not what you want.

Comment: @devilfart this is part of a class which is why I do not state function

Comment: I assume you get this error notification in your browser's JavaScript console. Can you look at the source that eventually is sent to the browser in your Developer Tools to see exactly what was printed?

Comment: @JanakaDissanayake Thank you! It turns out that I had an empty `onClick` statement and when I removed it everything was fixed!

Comment: You should submit that as an answer and mark it correct for future readers

Answer (score 0):

Because React Component's name must be in uppercase.

try

```
renderNavBar() {
        if (!this.userHash) {
            return ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<NavComponent.NavBarNoUser />);
        }
    }
```

navComponent change the name to NavComponent, navBarNoUser => NavBarNoUser

Answer (score 0):

So I found out that my tsx markup for the element was wrong.

Essentially, I kept an empty on click handler like this `onClick={}`.
This is what caused my errors.

Thanks